# numpy log2 zero masking only works outside of function

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter

I'm trying to implement a fast entropy calculation for a float list of probabilities.

Instead of looping through a list, checking if not zero each time, I'm attempting to mask zeros using numpy's built in masking functionality. It works absolutely fine, unless I try to put it into a function, at which point it breaks. Any suggestions?

```
# Works fine!!
distribution = np.array([0.20, 0.3, 0.25, 0.25, 0])

log_dist = np.log2(distribution, out=np.zeros_like(distribution), where=(distribution!=0))
entropy = -np.sum(distribution * log_dist)

print(entropy)
```

```
# Breaks!
def calculate_entropy(distribution):
    
    log_dist = np.log2(distribution, out=np.zeros_like(distribution), where=(distribution!=0))
    entropy = -np.sum(distribution * log_dist)
    
    return entropy

calculate_entropy([0.20, 0.3, 0.25, 0.25, 0])
```

output:
nan

Error message:
/var/folders/bt/vk3t9rnn2jz5d1wgj2rc3v200000gn/T/ipykernel_61321/2272953976.py:3: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log2
log_dist = np.log2(distribution, out=np.zeros_like(distribution), where=(distribution!=0))
/var/folders/bt/vk3t9rnn2jz5d1wgj2rc3v200000gn/T/ipykernel_61321/2272953976.py:4: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
entropy = -np.sum(distribution * log_dist)

I was expecting the function to work exactly the same, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, I'm an idiot. I forgot to convert the list into a numpy array. fix:

```py
def calculate_entropy(distribution):

    distribution = np.array(distribution)
    log_dist = np.log2(distribution, out=np.zeros_like(distribution), where=(distribution!=0))
    entropy = -np.sum(distribution * log_dist)
    
    return entropy

calculate_entropy([0.20, 0.3, 0.25, 0.25, 0])
```